# How can I run a .py file in a different .py file 10 times, each time posting the variables gotten from the first python file as a message in discord

Tags: python-3.x, discord, gmail-api, discord.py

```
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import base64
import time
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Gmail API
    repeat = 0
    while repeat <= 10:
        labelName = "READ-BY-SCRIPT"
        LABEL_ID = 'Label_8507504117657095973'
        results = service.users().messages().list(
            userId='me', q="-label:"+labelName, maxResults=1).execute()
        messages = results.get('messages', [])
        body = []
        if not messages:
            repeat += 10
            time.sleep(60)
        else:
            for message in messages:
                msg = service.users().messages().get(
                    userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
                labels = msg['labelIds']
                if "INBOX" in labels:
                    body.append(msg['payload']['parts'])
                    body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(
                        body[0][0]['body']['data'])
                    body = str(body)
                    if 'b"\\r\\nHi MOHAMMAD,\\r\\n' or "b'\\r\\nHi MOHAMMAD,\\r\\n" in body:
                        if 'posted a new assignment in IX K  \\r\\n<https://classroom.google.com/c/MTEyNDMxODgyMTE0>.' in body:
                            body = body.replace(
                                "\\r\\nIf you don\\'t want to receive emails from Classroom, you can unsubscribe  \\r\\n<https://classroom.google.com/s>.\\r\\n\\r\\nGoogle LLC\\r\\n1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy\\r\\nMountain View, CA 94043 USA\\r\\n'", "")
                            body = body.replace("b\"", "").replace("b'", "").replace('"', '').replace("   ", ' ').replace(
                                "  ", ' ').replace(" \\n<https://classroom.google.com/c/MTEyNDMxODgyMTE0>", "").replace("\\n", "\\n\\n")
                            body = body.replace("\\r\\n\\nHi MOHAMMAD,\\r\\n\\n", "").replace(" \\r\\n\\n<https://classroom.google.com/c/MTEyNDMxODgyMTE0>.\\r\\n", "").replace(
                                "\\r\\n\\nIf you don't want to receive emails from Classroom, you can unsubscribe \\r\\n\\n<https://classroom.google.com/s>.\\r\\n\\n\\r\\n\\nGoogle LLC\\r\\n\\n1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy\\r\\n\\nMountain View, CA 94043 USA\\r\\n\\n", "")
                            body = body.replace("\\r", "\r").replace(
                                "\\n", "\n").replace("\n\n", "\n").replace("\\\\", "\\")
                            body = body.replace("\\xe2", "").replace(
                                "\\x80", "").replace("\\x99", "").replace("\\x98", "")
                            body = body.replace(
                                "\\r\\nIf you don\\'t want to receive emails from Classroom, you can unsubscribe  \\r\\n<https://classroom.google.com/s>.\\r\\n\\r\\nGoogle LLC\\r\\n1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy\\r\\nMountain View, CA 94043 USA\\r\\n'", "")
                            body = body.replace("\\'", "")
                            body = body.replace(
                                "\\r\\nIf you don\\'t want to receive emails from Classroom, you can unsubscribe", "")
                            body = body.replace(
                                "If you dont want to receive emails from Classroom, you can unsubscribe\n <https://classroom.google.com/s>.\nGoogle LLC\n1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy\nMountain View, CA 94043 USA\n", "")

                            TEACHER_NAME = body.split("posted", 1)[0]
                            body = body.replace(TEACHER_NAME, "")
                            LINK = str(body.split("\r\nOPEN \r\n<", 1)[1])
                            LINK = LINK[:-1]
                            body = body.replace(LINK, "").replace("<", "").replace(">", "").replace(
                                'posted a new assignment in IX K\n\r\n', "").replace("\r\nOPEN \r\n", "")
                            if 'Due: ' in body:
                                body = body.replace("\n", "          ", 1)
                                DATE = body.split('          ')[0]
                                body = body.split('          ')[1]
                            else:
                                body = body
                                DATE = 'No Due Date Provided'
                                
                            service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=message['id'], body={
                                'addLabelIds': ['Label_8507504117657095973']}).execute()
                            repeat += 1
                        else:
                            service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=message['id'], body={
                                'addLabelIds': [LABEL_ID]}).execute()
                            pass
                    else:
                        service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=message['id'], body={
                            'addLabelIds': [LABEL_ID]}).execute()
                        pass
                else:
                    service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=message['id'], body={
                        'addLabelIds': ['Label_8507504117657095973']}).execute()
                    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This script gets the most recent unread email from gmail. If there are no new emails then it instantly ends the script. If there is an email that isn’t from google classroom it marks that email as read and then repeats the process again until a there are either no new unread emails or if an email from google classroom is found. If there is a new email from google classroom it gets the teacher’s name [TEACHER_NAME], link to the assignment [LINK], due date [DATE], and details of the assignment [body] and then ends the script

I want to make a different python file (bot.py) that runs another python file (gmail.py) containing the above script, 10 times. Each time gmail.py is run, bot.py via discord.py sends each of these variables in different messages if they are defined by gmail.py, and to do nothing if they are not defined by gmail.py. bot.py then waits 1 minute before repeating the entire process over again. How can this be done? Where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really 'run' the python file, you should rather import the file (or the function from the file) and run the function however many times fit using a for loop.